# What is this WHERE clause adding to the query?

Tags: sql

I am trying to better understand the answer to the following query: https://www.w3resource.com/sql-exercises/sql-subqueries-exercise-22.php

The answer is:

```
SELECT 
    departments.department_id, result1.total_amt 
FROM 
    departments,  
    (SELECT employees.department_id, SUM(employees.salary) total_amt  
     FROM employees  
     GROUP BY department_id) result1 
WHERE 
    result1.department_id = departments.department_id;
```

However, I do not understand why I need the last part:

```
WHERE result1.department_id = departments.department_id
```

Comment: You need it because you did not use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: It's an old, outdated way of specifying a join condition.

Comment: Try removing it and see what happens.

Comment: When you include more than one table in your SQL you must specify upon which columns the tables are related to one another. In this case `departments.department_id` is related to the derived table's`result1.department_id`. Generally we specify that with the `ON` clause in a `JOIN`, but you can also list the tables in the `FROM` comma separated like this and then specify the relationship in the `WHERE` clause. It's frowned upon though. If you fail to specify the relationship in an `ON` or `WHERE` then you will end up with every row in one table being joined to every other row in the other.